# Change function in responsive theme

Tags: responsive

I have this code on my header:

`$rPosts->query('showposts=3&cat=2174');`

But I want to show 4 posts on desktop and 2-3 on mobile. In CSS I could use @mediaqueries, could I use something like that on PHP?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a function called [`wp_is_mobile`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile). It does [very simple](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/vars.php#L106) [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) checking, which isn't very reliable. There are a lot of user agents out there and they can easily be falsified. There is no guarantee that a browser representing itself as some user agent actually is that user agent. You can do [more complicated user agent checking](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php) but it is still user agent checking.

But you also don't have a lot of choice with a server side script. I would use `wp_is_mobile`, or some more complicated version, to hedge my bets. It may save some load time in some, maybe many, cases. But make sure that media queries deal with the important stuff.

Comment: While this is technical options I want to stress that this is not reliable server side. Won't work at all (or will work faulty) with static page caching, etc.

Comment: I tried to make an smaller div with overflow hidden, but didn't work because some elements still show after that.