# enqueue styles for only mobile wp

Tags: functions, theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I tried to enqueue some styles on mobile only using `wp_is_mobile()` function, but it always give me true, Here is the code (From `functions.php` file) :

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_All_Styles'); // Set up styles

    function load_All_Styles() {
    wp_register_style('font-awesome',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome.min.css',array(),false);
    wp_register_style('preloader',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/preloader.css',array(),false);
    wp_register_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css',array(),false);

    if(wp_is_mobile()){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome' );

    }
    if(is_front_page()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'preloader' );
    }
}
```

what method to use instead? Any Solutions?

Comment: try to debug your code first and what you get?

Comment: Have you debug result of `wp_is_mobile`, that you see why is it `true`?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code of [`wp_is_mobile`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) you will see that this returns true based on the user agent sent by the browser. It looks for the word 'mobile' in the user agent's name or some other strings that point to mobile devices, like 'android' and 'kindle'. So, that should work.

However, if you are using any caching plugin [that plugin will serve the page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188881/proper-usage-of-wp-is-mobile) regardless of the user agent. After all, caching wouldn't make sense if you would rebuild the page every time a different user agent came in.