# Disabling Wp_is_mobile from backend?

Tags: plugins, mobile, responsive

I'm using a wordpress theme that makes use of wp_is_mobile function, but reacts badly on many occasion,
as it's being called in many files, I was wondering if you are aware of a wordpress plugin that would maybe 'disable' that functionnality or pretend we're never on mobile ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your theme may be using the [`wp_is_mobile`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) function incorrectly as it should not be used for theme specific styling, etc and is also unreliable as it only inspects the browser User-Agent. As I don't know what your theme is, I cannot say for definite if that is the case but see [this answer for more information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188897/190547) about that if you're interested.

As for the function itself, it will also have the boolean value pass through a filter under the same name before it is returned, [`wp_is_mobile`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_is_mobile/). But yes, it is entirely possible for a plugin, or theme, to cause the function to return falsey values.

I don't know of a specific plugin but if you would like to disable it yourself, you can add the following to the top of your theme `functions.php` file.

```php
add_filter( 'wp_is_mobile', function( $is_mobile ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $is_mobile;
    }
    
    return false;
} );
```

This will disable `wp_is_mobile` in your theme but allow it to work correctly when viewing your admin panel.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ampersarnie, it's working like a charm on my child theme. :) :)

Comment: @user2850378 You're welcome. Please also accept the answer.