# Hamburger Navigation Menu

Tags: menus, responsive

I have a Wordpress menu that I am using as a Hamburger menu for smaller mobile devices.   Since there really isn't a "hover" event for touch devices, I have changed the main menu items to show their corresponding sub menus on "click" (or "touch").   The problem is that I can't make the main menu items clickable.  Also, I don't see an option in "wp_nav_menu" to show the top level item on the submenu.  That is how I would be inclined to use it.  I need a workaround or something like that.

Comment: This sounds like a Javascript issue more than a WordPress issue. JQuery does have a [doubleclick event](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) maybe that will work for you?

Comment: I have been using the mmenu js script to handle mobile menus recently. Has lots of options and it's not too complicated to setup.

Comment: @N00b I'm not sure how reliable [`wp_is_mobile()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97906/7355) actually is so I would use that function with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this with other nasty hacks but here's *kind of* WordPress way:

**In your `header.php`**

```
<?php
// User is not using mobile
if( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {

    wp_nav_menu(); // Your "original menu"    
}
// User is using mobile
else if( wp_is_mobile() ) {

    wp_nav_menu(); // Your another menu that only has top level items
}
?>
```

Keep in mind that `wp_is_mobile()` also considers tablets as mobile devices and you should always carefully think this through because if PC window is resized to small / narrow -> it obviously doesn't count it as mobile.

**And jQuery to disable your click event:**

```
var isMobile = false;

// Check if user is using mobile device
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

    isMobile = true;
}

if( ! isMobile ) {

    // Your usual click event
}
```

Comment: `wp_is_mobile()` is a joke and should be regarded as such, unless you are happy with between 80-90% success rate and happy to to dish wrong info to all the other users ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This works well.   The second click goes to the page...

```
$(".smallNavigation > ul > li > a").click(function (e) {

    $("ul.sub-menu").hide();
    $("ul.sub-menu", $(this).parent("li")).show();

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).unbind(e);

})
```